# EditModePanel in Display mode not showing for all authenticated users

Tags: permissions, publishing

I've got a Publishing Layout with some content placed inside an `EditModePanel` the `PageDisplayMode` of which is set to `Display`. This is to hide the contents when the page is in Edit mode.

**However, I recently discovered that one of the authenticated users does not see the contents of the EditModePanel.** For other users, with higher credentials, the content is displayed.

**The user who cannot see the contents is an authenticated user on the local machine with explicit Read rights to the root web who is not a member of any SharePoint groups.**

I've [read that only authenticated users](http://karthikshare.blogspot.com/2010/09/anonymous-access-and-editmodepanel.html) can see the contents of an `EditModePanel`, regardless of the `DisplayMode`, but in this case, the user is authenticated (and the name appears in the ribbon).

What's up?

(I haven't experimented with adding more Rights to the user since I fear an `EditModePanel` is not at all approriate for this scenario.)

**EDIT:** According to the Community Content on the [MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.editmodepanel.pagedisplaymode.aspx#1),

> Behaviour change in SharePoint 2010
>   When PageDisplayMode="Display", the
>   panel is **only rendered for users that
>   have edit permission to the page**.

Is this correct? To which "edit permission" does this refer? I cannot reproduce this consistently either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the behavior of the EditModePanel was changed in 2010 so that only people with Edit permissions on the page can see the content, even if the panel is set to Display.

http://doseofdotnet.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/editmodepanel-behavior-changes-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I commented on this theory in the question. I don't buy it, and can't reproduce it, and I think an authoritative citation is needed.

Comment: Nothing on MS site, but I did find about a dozen blogs that all say the same thing, including this one that Reflected the code and verified that the logic has changed:
http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2010/12/04/about-editmodepanel-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thanks. That's very strange. Even stranger that I cannot reproduce it consistently; must be something with the EditListItems permissions on the groups my users are in.

Comment: This is correct. The behaviour changed in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

*(This should be a comment, but restrictions apply...)*

I guess this is to streamline the usage of the DisplayModePanel.

It's traditionally used to only show specific content when the page is in EditMode. Thus, the person will have the Edit Permissions.

Use of DisplayMode="Display" was a kind of hack to let you hide content when in Edit Mode.

The purpose of the Page Layout system is to let your power users design Page Layouts in a WYSIWYG manner, such that when the user comes along to create/edit pages, they will edit the content panes that will be in the exact same position as they will be when rendered.

Allowing the use of DisplayMode="Display", in my experience, proliferated abuse of this control, and Page Layouts tended to have two EditModePanels in a page, both with duplicated data in them representing the content fields, with very subtle differences between the two, and the differences themselves being fundamentally incorrect implementations of SharePoint artefacts (such as FieldControls changing the format of a Content Type Column, where the formatting could be better set in the column itself).

To help you more (and help you give an answer, rather than explain why the behaviour was changed), could you let us know just why you want content hidden in the Display mode?

Comment: What I want to do here isn't *hide* content in Display mode, but *display* content in Display mode. One example is a page which shows animated rich content, which interfers with the editing experience. The content should be editable in Edit mode, using fields on the page, but to display the content in its "display mode" while editing simply does not work.